# What "base" to use when building .msi for GUI application written in python? CX-Freeze

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, export, cx-freeze

I'm trying to export a simple GUI application I wrote in python with cx-freeze using this script, that I found in the documentation of the cx-freeze website.

http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils

In the script it says that GUI applications requires a different "base" than console applications (which is the default used in the script).

If it's any help I use tkinter to create the GUI application.

Here is the setup script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "Feet2Meter",
        version = "1",
        description = "Transform feet to meters",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("Feet2Meter.py", base=base)])
```

I have also removed ' "excludes": [tkinter] ' in my own script, as that is what I use to make the GUI application and don't want to exlude it.

If you need more clarification I'll be happy to provide.

Answer (score -1):

The `Win32GUI` base is the want you want. The comment is describing why that bit of code is setting a different base on Windows. "default" means what it would use without that bit of code.